# Haskell/GHC: How to write predicates on type-level naturals

Tags: haskell, ghc, predicates

I could have sworn I saw an article on this recently, but I can't find it.

I'm trying to make a type to do binary encoding of the numbers mod `n`, but to do so, I need to be able to write predicates on the type level naturals:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module Modulo where

-- (pseudo-)binary representation of 
-- numbers mod n
--
--  e.g. Mod Seven contains
--    Zero . Zero . Zero $ Stop
--    Zero . Zero . One  $ Stop
--    Zero . One . Zero $ Stop
--    Zero . One . One  $ Stop
--    One . Zero . Zero $ Stop
--    One . Zero . One  $ Stop
--    One . One $ Stop 
data Mod n where
  Stop :: Mod One
  Zero :: Split n => Mod (Lo n) -> Mod n
  One  :: Split n => Mod (Hi n) -> Mod n

-- type-level naturals
data One
data Succ n 
type Two = Succ One

-- predicate to allow us to compare 
-- natural numbers
class Compare n n' b | n n' -> b

-- type-level ordering
data LT
data EQ
data GT

-- base cases
instance Compare One One EQ
instance Compare One (Succ n) LT
instance Compare (Succ n) One GT

-- recurse
instance Compare n n' b => Compare (Succ n) (Succ n') b

-- predicate to allow us to break down
-- natural numbers by their bit structure
--
-- if every number mod n can be represented in m bits, then
class Split n where
  type Lo n -- number of values mod n where the m'th bit is 0
  type Hi n -- number of values mod n where the m'th bit is 1

-- base case, n = 2
-- for this, we only need m=1 bit
instance Split Two where
  type Lo Two = One -- 0 mod 2
  type Hi Two = One -- 1 mod 2

-- recurse
--  if (Lo n) == (Hi n), then n = 2^m, so
--  the values mod (n+1) will require one extra bit
instance (Split n, Compare (Lo n) (Hi n) EQ) => Split (Succ n) where
  type Lo (Succ n) = n    -- all the numbers mod n will be prefixed by a 0
  type Hi (Succ n) = One  -- and one extra, which will be 10...0

-- recurse
--  if (Lo n) > (Hi n), then n < 2^m, so
--  the values mod (n+1) still only require m bits
instance (Split n, Compare (Lo n) (Hi n) GT) => Split (Succ n) where
  type Lo (Succ n) = Lo (n)       -- we've got the same number of lower values
  type Hi (Succ n) = Succ (Hi n)  -- and one more higher value
```

My current implementation spits out a bunch of compiler errors:

```
Nat.hs:60:8:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      type Lo Two -- Defined at Nat.hs:60:8-9
      type Lo (Succ n) -- Defined at Nat.hs:74:8-9

Nat.hs:61:8:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      type Hi Two -- Defined at Nat.hs:61:8-9
      type Hi (Succ n) -- Defined at Nat.hs:75:8-9

Nat.hs:66:10:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance (Split n, Compare (Lo n) (Hi n) EQ) => Split (Succ n)
        -- Defined at Nat.hs:66:10-62
      instance (Split n, Compare (Lo n) (Hi n) GT) => Split (Succ n)
        -- Defined at Nat.hs:73:10-62

Nat.hs:67:8:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      type Lo (Succ n) -- Defined at Nat.hs:67:8-9
      type Lo (Succ n) -- Defined at Nat.hs:74:8-9

Nat.hs:68:8:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      type Hi (Succ n) -- Defined at Nat.hs:68:8-9
      type Hi (Succ n) -- Defined at Nat.hs:75:8-9
```

Which makes me think I'm going about writing my predicates wrong, if it thinks they're conflicting.

How can I do them right?

Comment: By "naturals", do you mean "natural numbers"?

Comment: Type families and overlapping instances don't work together right now. Take a peek over at http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4259

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The conflict problem is simple enough. The [rules for overlapping type families](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html#type-family-overlap) are quite simple:

> The instance declarations of a type family used in a single program may only overlap if the right-hand sides of the overlapping instances coincide for the overlapping types. More formally, two instance declarations overlap if there is a substitution that makes the left-hand sides of the instances syntactically the same. Whenever that is the case, the right-hand sides of the instances must also be syntactically equal under the same substitution.

Note that it specifies *syntactically* equal. Consider these two instances:

```
instance Split Two where
  type Lo Two = One -- 0 mod 2
  type Hi Two = One -- 1 mod 2

instance Split (Succ n) where
  type Lo (Succ n) = Lo (n)  
  type Hi (Succ n) = Succ (Hi n)
```

`Two` is defined as `Succ One`, and plain type synonyms are expanded for purposes of syntactic equality, so these are equal on the left-hand sides; but the right-hand sides are not, hence the error.

You may have noticed that I removed the class context from the above code. The deeper problem, and perhaps why you didn't expect the above conflict to occur, is that the duplicate instances really *are* conflicting duplicates. Class contexts are, as always, ignored for purposes of instance selection, and if memory serves me this goes double for associated type families, which are largely a syntactic convenience for unassociated type families and may not be constrained by the class in ways you'd expect.

Now, clearly those two instances *should* be distinct, and you'd like to chose between them based on the result of using `Compare`, therefore that result must be a *parameter* of the type class, not merely a constraint. You're also mixing type families with functional dependencies here, which is needlessly awkward. So, starting from the top, we'll keep the basic types:

```
-- type-level naturals
data One
data Succ n 
type Two = Succ One

-- type-level ordering
data LT
data EQ
data GT
```

Rewrite the `Compare` function as a type family:

```
type family Compare n m :: *
type instance Compare One One = EQ
type instance Compare (Succ n) One = GT
type instance Compare One (Succ n) = LT
type instance Compare (Succ n) (Succ m) = Compare n m
```

Now, to handle the conditional we'll need some sort of "flow control" type family. I'll define something a bit more general here for edification and inspiration; specialize according to taste.

We'll give it a predicate, an input, and two branches to chose from:

```
type family Check pred a yes no :: *
```

We'll need a predicate for testing `Compare`'s result:

```
data CompareAs a
type instance (CompareAs LT) LT yes no = yes 
type instance (CompareAs EQ) LT yes no = no
type instance (CompareAs GT) LT yes no = no
type instance (CompareAs LT) EQ yes no = no 
type instance (CompareAs EQ) EQ yes no = yes
type instance (CompareAs GT) EQ yes no = no
type instance (CompareAs LT) GT yes no = no
type instance (CompareAs EQ) GT yes no = no
type instance (CompareAs GT) GT yes no = yes
```

That's a frightfully tedious set of definitions, granted, and the prognosis is quite grim for comparing larger sets of type-values. More extensible approaches exist (a pseudo-kind tag and a bijection with the naturals being an obvious and effective solution) but that's a bit beyond the scope of this answer. I mean, we're just doing type-level computation here, let's not get *ridiculous* or anything.

Simpler in this case would be to simply define a case analysis function on comparison results:

```
type family CaseCompare cmp lt eq gt :: *
type instance CaseCompare LT lt eq gt = lt
type instance CaseCompare EQ lt eq gt = eq
type instance CaseCompare GT lt eq gt = gt
```

I'll use the latter for now, but if you want more complex conditionals elsewhere a generic approach begins to make more sense.

Anyway. We can split the... er, `Split` class into unassociated type families:

```
data Oops

type family Lo n :: *
type instance Lo Two = One
type instance Lo (Succ (Succ n)) 
    = CaseCompare (Compare (Lo (Succ n)) (Hi (Succ n)))
                  Oops -- yay, type level inexhaustive patterns
                  (Succ n)
                  (Lo (Succ n))

type family Hi n :: *
type instance Hi Two = One
type instance Hi (Succ (Succ n)) 
    = CaseCompare (Compare (Lo (Succ n)) (Hi (Succ n)))
                  Oops -- yay, type level inexhaustive patterns
                  One
                  (Succ (Hi (Succ n)))
```

The most significant point here is the (seemingly redundant) use of `(Succ (Succ n))`--the reason for this is that two `Succ` constructors are necessary to distinguish the argument from `Two`, thus avoiding the conflict errors you saw.

Note that I've moved everything to type families here for simplicity, as it's all entirely type-level. If you also wish to handle values differently depending on the above calculations--including indirectly, via the `Mod` type--you may need to add appropriate class definitions back, since those are required for choosing terms based on type, rather than merely choosing types based on types.